# bq fails with "close failed in file object destructor / IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

Tags: google-bigquery

I am learning to use bq, after having spent a few days using successfully the interactive developers console to load data into BigQuery.

Today I was to upload my first properly formatted CSV file using bq when I got this error at the end of the process:

```
close failed in file object destructor:  
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Waiting on bqjob_r1581e771414c555a_00000143f71d0a99_1 ... (49s) Current status: DONE
```

The csv file is a >600k rows, >117 Mb one.

I have repeated the 'experiment' and had no issues the second time. I would like to understand if Is it a problem my side or BigQuery's, as I need to script the call to bq to work over a large number of files and I want to understand to what degree I need to manage exceptions.

I am using Homebrew's Python 2.7.6 on MacOS 10.9.1 .

Thanks!

Giacecco

Answer (score 0):

"IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" usually means local file system problems.

See [What can lead to "IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" during os.system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686275/what-can-lead-to-ioerror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor-during-os-system) for more details.