# Why am I getting this error OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor? Occurs when closing a file using f.close()

Tags: python-3.x

while closing the file I get this OSError. Can anyone explains what's going wrong?

```
>>> f=open('fr.txt','w')
>>> print('hey',file=f)
>>> f.close()


OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: What Python version are you using?  What operating system?  Does the file exist already?  Can you write to other files?  Does it happen reliably with this file?  I can run this code on my machine with no errors (after creating a fr.txt file), so there's something else going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can lead to "IOError: \[Errno 9\] Bad file descriptor" during os.system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686275/what-can-lead-to-ioerror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor-during-os-system)