# I am trying to create a new project with pycharm but

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to create a new project, but I get this error:

Error: Command '['C:\Users\Rosca\PycharmProjects\Mark\venv\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip? python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: @SequenceToSequence E:\Python 3.6.0\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: It seems like you might have a problem with your python install. Is python correctly added to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: @SequenceToSequence So I have reinstalled python with PATH but it seems like it gives me this error when I try to install a package: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error you are getting that `pip` can't be found (after a fresh Python install) is a clear sign you didn't add it to your Operating System's environment variables, see [How do I add Python to the Windows PATH?](https://superuser.com/a/143121) also in the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) afterwards don't forget to [configure the interpreter inside the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)

Comment: Besides the error message as present is somewhat strange since you don't include further details of how your OS and IDE are configured. Apparently you are trying to create a new project using a venv, but there are insufficient details to elaborate further.

Comment: @bad_coder So I configured the IDE and it shows me to install packaging tool, but when  I press it it tells me this: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: @RVGamer currently SO [only has1 post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+OSError%3A+Bad+file+descriptor+) for this error on the PyCharm tag with some experienced members saying it might be a bug and you should use `pip` on the command line instead of the GUI. Here's [another explanation of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7686464). Anyway, you question should be edited to include lots of details, at this point readers don't have a description of your environment nor a screenshot so there's nothing more to go on.