# ERROR:root:'Process' object has no attribute 'get_open_files'

Tags: python-3.x

Running the code below associated with the answer of @s3ni0r [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329917/restart-python-script-from-within-itself/33334183#33334183) using python 3.8

```
import os
import sys
import psutil
import logging

def restart_program():
    """Restarts the current program, with file objects and descriptors
       cleanup
    """

    try:
        p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        for handler in p.get_open_files() + p.connections():
            os.close(handler.fd)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)
```

runs into

```
ERROR:root:'Process' object has no attribute 'get_open_files'
```

Does anyone know what should be updated?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `get_open_files()` with `open_files()`

Comment: Now, I get `ERROR:root:[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/7686464/17198281