# Socket IO transport 404

Tags: reactjs, sockets, nginx, flask, socket.io

I'm attempting to connect a simple socket-io application using server side react and python. I'm getting a 404 on the socket connect. The issue is that there are too many moving pieces for me to know what's going on and debug the error (ie NGINX, python, react, Cloudflare). The code is as far as I can make a prototypical example as simple as I can make it.

Here's the NGINX code -

```
server {
  
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name abookoftwelveflowers.com www.abookoftwelveflowers.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl                    on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare_book.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/cloudflare_book.pem;

    server_name abookoftwelveflowers.com www.abookoftwelveflowers.com;

    location / {
            #root /NEST/stream/front/build;
            #index index.htl index.htm
            proxy_pass http://unix:/NEST/stream/back_flask/guni_one.sock;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Here's the Python Code -

gunicorn

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r /NEST/stream/front/files /NEST/stream/front/build/files
gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:guni_two.sock -m 007  wsgiapi:app --daemon
```

wsgi.py

```
#!/bin/env python
  

from my_app import app, sio

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app, debug=True)
    #app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=4000, debug=True, threaded=True, ssl_context="adhoc")
```

my_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

#import socketio
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../front/build", static_url_path="/")
CORS(app)

sio = SocketIO()

@sio.on('connect')
def test_connect(auth):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})

@sio.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

@sio.on('message')
def handle_message(data):
    print('received message: ' + data)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")

...other routes...
```

and on the main page of my application

```
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation.js"
import Webcounter from "../components/Webcounter.js"

import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

function Main() {
  let history = useHistory();

  const socketfunc = () => {
    console.log('inside socketfunc in Main.js');
    const socket = io('https://www.abookoftwelveflowers.com')
    console.log('value of socket: ', socket);
    socket.on('connect', (socket) => {
      console.log('value of socket inside connect: ', socket);
    })
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('inside useEffect for Main.js')
    socketfunc()
  }, []);
```

When I run the code the website works - I can access the front end and back end routes, however socket io repeatedly fails and the error that is in the web console is this -

```
GET https://www.abookoftwelveflowers.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NrXngtX 404
```

And this matches the output from `/var/log/nginx/` which looks like:

```
172.70.178.17 - - [27/Nov/2021:14:49:49 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NrXtx0u HTTP/2.0" 502 568 "https://abookoftwelveflowers.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36"
```

So, I think that the issue is coming from NGINX in the way that I am using `.sock` as the proxy_pass but I'm not sure what exactly. It's the way I (finally) was able to get NGINX to work, so I don't want to necessarily change it to using a port number if I don't have to. Any suggestions?

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

EDIT -

So this has a lot of moving pieces and I think I'm closer do to a comment / suggestion below to change `SocketIo()` to `SocketIo(app)`. Sorry if this isn't an ideal "how do I solve x bug", but stack tracing through several programs is difficult. The changes that I've made are the following

On the client -

```
  const socketfunc = () => {
    console.log('inside socketfunc in Main.js');
    const socket = io('https://www.abookoftwelveflowers.com', {path: '/socket.io'})
    console.log('value of socket: ', socket);
    socket.on('connect', (socket) => {
      console.log('value of socket inside connect: ', socket);
    })
  }
```

On the server -

```
sio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", path='/socket.io')
```

In gunicorn -

```
gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:guni_one.sock -m 001  wsgi:app
```

In NGINX -

```
location /socket.io/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/NEST/stream/back_flask/guni_one.sock;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/NEST/stream/back_flask/guni_one.sock;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I've tried using `0.0.0.0:<PORT>` in gunicorn and NGINX and also played around with using `/socket.io/` and `/socket.io` in order to send the request. As far as I can tell the incoming and outgoing requests are symmetric.

I've also set gunicorn to only one worker. The documentation (https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html) is confusing in that it says that if you use `socketio.run(app)` then the number of workers may or may not matter, but just in case...

Anyway I have the following error. From what I can read online ([What can lead to "IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" during os.system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686275/what-can-lead-to-ioerror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor-during-os-system)) the `OS ERROR Bad File Descriptor` is due to no properly closing a file read/write. Why this should be happening on a socket call I don't know.

Here is the error. Once the error is logged gunicorn kills the worker and cycles another, attempts a reconnect of the socket and then the worker dies again. I'll continue to debug, but if there are any suggestions that would be pleasant. Thanks

```
Invalid session K13_ryJcNNXj7dKWAAAn (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)
Client disconnected
inside the test_connect handler
[2021-11-27 23:50:05 +0000] [3422698] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 190, in handle_request
    util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 650, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 181, in handle_request
    resp.write(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 326, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 322, in send_headers
    util.write(self.sock, util.to_bytestring(header_str, "latin-1"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 311, in write
    sock.sendall(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Hey there, do you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an idea of why it's not working. You put in your Flask app:

> `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../front/build", static_url_path="/")`

which is saying to have the static path as the root path. In other words, if there's not an explicit route for it in your app, then it'll try to find and serve a file from `../front/build`.

This would also explain the 502 - Bad Gateway error in your nginx log.

EDIT: I have tested this theory and it seems to not have affected anything. However, now I see that you just did

> `sio = SocketIO()`

without passing in `app`, which could be another reason for why it's not working.

Comment: That was part of the problem! See my edit above - Thanks for the suggestions!