# Python txt file write issue

Tags: python

new to Python.

Even when doing a simple write to file I get an error

simple code

```
text = "Sample text."
saveFile = open("file.txt", "w")
saveFile.write(text)
saveFile.close()
```

error
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Tony\Documents\PythonCourse\App1\tester.py", line 4, in <module>
saveFile.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

doing this without a close does not give an error but does not write to the file.

I'm lost as to what to try next

Comment: This works just fine, so you're going to have to get a lot more detailed: which OS? (Obviously windows, but which one?) Which version of Python? What execution environment?

Comment: I think the most likely cause is that the file was never actually opened.  Try leaving out the `write` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Sorry. 

Windows 11. 
IDE is pycharm

Comment: If I leave out the write, I do not get an error

Comment: python version is 3.11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can lead to "IOError: \[Errno 9\] Bad file descriptor" during os.system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686275/what-can-lead-to-ioerror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor-during-os-system)

Comment: Also works for me on Windows 11. Try in a python console, try different folder, make sure you have free storage/are allowed to write, make sure the file is NOT currently open/edited with another program. Try to modify to another filename, if this works the first time. Its rather an OS file locked by something else problem.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will work as if the "saveFile.write(text)" throws any kind of error, so it won't allow us to close our file (saveFile.close()) it could be resolved using the exception handling.

```
text = "Sample text."
saveFile = open("file.txt", "w")
try:
    saveFile.write(text)
finally:
    saveFile.close()
```

Comment: C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:\Users\Tony\Documents\PythonCourse\App1\tester.py 
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tony\Documents\PythonCourse\App1\tester.py", line 6, in <module>
    saveFile.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Process finished with exit code 1